# Is it possible to define a range of months as a variable in vbscript for mssql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I have two forms that people can fill out to report information about students. Then I have a third form in which they select the student and semester and it will display all of the reports about the selected student from form one and two in one place.

Reports one and two have a date variable that is sent to the database table along with the information entered into the form.

Depending on which semester is selected I'm trying to pull the reports from only those months. January through April for Spring, May through August for Summer and September through December for Fall.

```
Dim submitDate

submitDate=date()
```

On form three this is my selection box.

```
<label for="BySemester">Select semester</label>  
<select size="1" name="BySemester">
<option value="Spring">Spring</option>
<option value="Summer">Summer</option>
<option value="Fall">Fall</option>
</select>
```

I tried to define semester as a variable and create an if else if statement but it doesn't seem to be working

```
Dim conn
Dim strconn
Dim studentName 
Dim semester   
Dim rsFacReport
Dim runFRspring

studentName=request.form.item(2)
semester=request.form.item(3)

If semester=Spring Then

runFRspring = "Select * from table name where studentName = '" & StudentName & "' and datepart(month,DateSubmitted)= BETWEEN '01' AND '04' "
runFRspring = runFRspring & "order by DateSubmitted"

set rsFacReport = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsFacReport.Open runFRspring, conn, 3, 3 

code to loop through fields and write out

ElseIf semester=Summer Then
....

ElseIf semester=Fall Then
....

Else
response.write "No records found"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
If semester=Spring Then
```

should be

```
If semester = "Spring" Then
```

(Do you use "Option Explicit"?)

**Update wrt comment:**

Maybe

```
... and datepart(month,DateSubmitted)= BETWEEN '01' AND '04'
```

should be

```
... and datepart(month,DateSubmitted) BETWEEN 1 AND 4
```

(DatePart returns int; no need for =)

Answer (score 0):

```
 If semester=Spring Then
```

should be

```
If semester="Spring" Then
```